# Exporting Data to a Newly Generated Spreadsheet From Another Spreadheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a button that generates a new spreadsheet everytime that it is pressed.
That part is working perfectly fine.

However, I additionally want the new spreadsheet to be a summary of data for what is in my 'Mother' spreadsheet. I want to be able to write a script in the 'Mother' Spreadsheet that I can link to another button that, when pressed, extracts data from the 'Mother' Spreadsheet and sends it to the newly generated Spreadsheet. There seems to be a way to do this using Spreadsheet Ids, but I ran into some problems because I generate about 100 new reports from the Main Spreadsheet and the data needs to be exported Immediately.

Here is the code so far:

```
     function NewSpreadsheets() {
  var FromDate = String(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B3').getValue());
  var ToDate = String(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C3').getValue());;  
  var SpreadsheetName = FromDate + ' to ' + ToDate + ' Summary';
  var NewSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(SpreadsheetName, 101, 5);
}
```

Comment: Describe in some more detail the problems and errors you were getting, and put in the code you have so far for doing the copy.

Comment: Well, the problems I ran into were not 'result problems', but being unable to find a suitable method to transport some - not all - data from the Main sheet to the newly generated sheet having only the new sheet's name (var SpreadsheetName) to locate it.

Comment: Additionally, it should be noted that I need it to be a script that runs on a click of a button.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your issue here. Why is it that you cannot just use the variable `NewSpreadsheet` that you just retrieved, which refers to the newly created spreadsheet, in order to update this new spreadsheet? Also, if you want to do this with two different buttons, you could store the spreadsheet `ID` using PropertiesService and retrieve in the second function.

Comment: Take a look at the docs on getRange() and getValues() - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet

Comment: lamblichus, could you show an example of code taking the value from , say, cell A1 in the main sheet and putting it in cell A2 of the new sheet. A basic form of this code:        'function Export () {'

Comment: function Export () { var value =SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID1").getRange('a1').getValue(); SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID2").getRange('a2').setValue(value); } now how do I get the ID2 of the second sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to have 2 buttons: one to create a new spreadsheet, and another one to add the data from the original spreadsheet, you can use PropertiesService in the first function to store the created spreadsheet `ID`, which can be retrieved in the second one:

> Function attached to **first button**:

```js
function createNewSpreadsheet() {
  var FromDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B3').getValue();
  var ToDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C3').getValue(); 
  var SpreadsheetName = FromDate + ' to ' + ToDate + ' Summary';
  var NewSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(SpreadsheetName, 101, 5);
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty("Copy ID", NewSpreadsheet.getId()); // Store spreadsheet ID
}
```

> Function attached to **second button**:

```js
function copyDataToNewSpreadsheet() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var spreadsheetId = scriptProperties.getProperty("Copy ID"); // Retrieve spreadsheet ID
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  // Copy data...
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)